# 64bit apps on a 32bit OS with a 64bit cpu

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, 32-bit

This question is a little bit stupid, but i wanna know. I wanna have 32bit windows in a vm beacuse it takes less space and it runs faster. Would it be posibble to run 64bit apps in a VM running 32bit windows with a 64bit cpu (my computer has a 64bit cpu)?

Thanks

Comment: 64-bit software only runs in 64-bit OSes. The CPU is irrelevant. It is possible to run 32-bit software in 64-bit OSes (most of the times).

Comment: "Would it be possible to run 64bit apps in a VM running 32bit windows" - No;  What you want is impossible. 32-bit versions of WIndows can only run 32-bit processes.

Comment: Sad that its not posibble. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @John: Your answer is correct, but no point in persisting with it. I voted to close this question and you could too.

Answer (score 1):

No, that’s not happening. To run 64-bit applications, you need a 64-bit operating system. That’s because the 32-bit and 64-bit worlds are mostly separate. A 32-bit kernel cannot run 64-bit applications. The CPU is in a different *mode*.

If we take a look beyond Windows, more exotic combinations are possible. You can easily run a system with an all-32-bit userland on a 64-bit kernel on Linux. Even though the kernel is 64-bit, you still could not run (most) 64-bit applications, because they expect 64-bit libraries that aren’t there.

You can use a different solution though: versions of VirtualBox and VMware Workstation (or Player) that are compatible with 32-bit Windows operating systems on the host can still run 64-bit guests if the CPU can. This works using hardware virtualization (VT-x or AMD-V).

Also, reconsider: Certainly, pointers are double the size in 64-bit software. However, software is made from more than pointers. 64-bit mode on modern CPUs unlocks more powerful instructions and wider registers. There is some overhead, yes, but unless you are seriously low on physical memory (4 GiB or less), you should not be using a 32-bit operating system!

Furthermore, running a 32-bit operating system as a VM guest gets you *nothing*. Instead, you are wasting a considerable amount of resources by running two operating systems at once.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: apps compiled for 64bit architecture will not run on 32bit architecture. The instructions used are simply different because 32bit uses 32 bits to allocate memory addresses, which limits to about 3,5 GB, whereas 64bits go a lot higher.

Even though your processor is 64 bit, everything must be 64-bit for it to work. That means, the processor, the OS and the program must be compiled for 64-bits too.

If you have a 32-bit version of that app, then you can install a 32-bit OS and use the 32-bit version of the app.